# How to pick out all non-NULL value from multiple columns in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I had a DataFrame like below:

```
       column-a         column-b      column-c
0          Nan             A              B
1           A              Nan            C
2           Nan            Nan            C
3           A              B              C
```

I hope to create a new column-D to capture all non-NULL values from column A to C:

```
        column d
0        A,B
1        A,C
2        C
3        A,B,C
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the `'Nan'` to `np.nan`, then using `stack` with `groupby` `join`

```
df=df.replace('Nan',np.nan)
df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
Out[570]: 
0      A,B
1      A,C
2        C
3    A,B,C
dtype: object

#df['column-d']= df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Comment: Wen, thanks for solution. If A,B,C were replaced as the numerical numbers: 1,2,3, could I sum them as a total?

Comment: @JennyJingYu then just do df.sum(1)

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the `nan`s:

```
df = df.replace('Nan', np.nan)
```

collect all non-null values in each row in a list and join the list items.

```
df['column-d'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis=1)
#0      A,B
#1      A,C
#2        C
#3    A,B,C
```

Surprisingly, this solution is somewhat faster than the `stack/groupby` solution by Wen, at least for the posted dataset.