# Select all non null rows from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, I need to select all the records which doesn't contain null values (NAN) in any of the column, without providing the column names

How can I do it with python pandas

Comment: This post might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231779/7965185

Comment: That post is about finding the non null values from rows.  I am interested in finding only those rows, which don't have null in any of the columns.

Comment: Then use `df = df.dropna()`